# Eclipse not showing project for the server

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

I have problem with the Eclipse and the servers... I had installed the Weblogic server and after configuring everything I was able to see the projects when I clicked on servers and try to Add and Remove. But later I needed to install also the Tomcat and for some reason after that I was not able to see the projects there... I removed the Tomcat, but it did not solve the problem. Also I've:

1. Configured the project facet to use `Dynamic Web Module` and `Java`.
2. Selected Weblogic in `Targeted Runtimes`.
3. I checked if Java runtimes are the same for each project and also the server.
4. I compared the properties and configurations of each project module of the same project on another PC. It looks the same. And on other PC it works. On mine it also worked at the beginning. What is more, the configuration of the project on this other PC was prepared based on my configuration in Eclipse...

I don't know what I should do to make it work again... Maybe some hidden configuration files or properties? I don't know...

BTW what will happen if I would remove this folder:
`.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects` ??

Some information:

- Server Oracle Weblogic 12c
- Tomcat no longer needed, so has been removed
- Eclipse Neon 4.x (I will update this tomorrow, because I don't remember)
- Runtimes set up for JRE 7
- Maven project devided into submodules: 2 ears, each contains 1 war, both wars contains common 2 jars.
- EAR projects has EAR 6.0 in facet configuration
- WAR projects has Dynamic Web Module 3.0, Java 7, JPA 2.0 (probably) and Javascript in facet
- JAR projects just Java 7
- There is also other Gradle project, the front-end one, which looks like that: EAR which contains the WAR
- Here in facet is also the same situation like with Maven projects

Comment: ```I compared the properties and configurations of each project module``` Well, *we* can't see that. What are the facets that are currently on the projects? Which version of Tomcat is involved? Which version of Eclipse? Do **not** go spelunking in your metadata folder as a solution.

Comment: By comparing I meant that I compared the properties of the project in Eclipse. So the project facets, deployment assemblies and stuff like that. It looks the same. And what is more, everything was fine at the beginning. Just one day it stopped working... So general configuration is correct...

Comment: Something about the configuration must not be correct, or you wouldn't be here. It's either something you've not accounted for, or something you've overlooked. And we haven't seen the relevant details.

Comment: Yeah but I didn't change anything. Everything was working. One day I've added Tomcat and it stopped working... I've updated the question with some details. Tell me what else is needed.